# OpenXML scheme color transformations - applying <a:gamma> and <a:invgamma>

Tags: c#, openxml, drawingml

When processing an open xml document, colors can have various transformations applied to a base color to generate a relative color. For instance `<a:satMod value="25000">` would modify the base colors saturation by 25%. There are two transforms I have been able to find very little information on and they are:

```
<a:gamma>
```

The docs say "This element specifies that the output color rendered by the generating application should be the sRGB gamma shift of the input color."

and

```
<a:invGamma>
```

The docs say "This element specifies that the output color rendered by the generating application should be the inverse sRGB gamma shift of the input color."

I would like to understand what calculation I would have to do on the base color to transform it using either of these transformations. Has anybody figured this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. Simply put,

- `<a:gamma>` simply means to take the sRGB value (0-1 scale) and linearize it (convert to linear RGB). Take those linear RGB values and save them as sRGB (and convert to 0-255 range if you want).
- `<a:invGamma>` is the opposite - take the linear RGB value (0-1 scale) and delinearize it (convert to sRGB). Take those delinearized RGB values and save them as sRGB (and convert to 0-255 range if you want).

So what is linear RGB? The calculation is [here on Wikipedia's sRGB page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#Specification_of_the_transformation).

Here's also a VBA version:

```
Public Function sRGB_to_linearRGB(value As Double) 
   If value < 0# Then 
      sRGB_to_linearRGB = 0# 
      Exit Function 
   End If 
   If value <= 0.04045 Then 
      sRGB_to_linearRGB = value / 12.92 
      Exit Function 
   End If 
   If value <= 1# Then 
      sRGB_to_linearRGB = ((value + 0.055) / 1.055) ^ 2.4 
      Exit Function 
   End If 
   sRGB_to_linearRGB = 1# 
End Function 

Public Function linearRGB_to_sRGB(value As Double) 
   If value < 0# Then 
      linearRGB_to_sRGB = 0# 
      Exit Function 
   End If 
   If value <= 0.0031308 Then 
      linearRGB_to_sRGB = value * 12.92 
      Exit Function 
   End If 
   If value < 1# Then 
      linearRGB_to_sRGB = 1.055 * (value ^ (1# / 2.4)) - 0.055 
      Exit Function 
   End If 
   linearRGB_to_sRGB = 1# 
End Function
```

The `value` that you pass in is the R, G, B component in 0-1 range, either sRGB or linear RGB. You'll receive the same range back, 0-1, and depending on your needs, you can then convert to 0-255 range to construct your color.